# Three column layout with minimum height 100%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to create a `three column layout` with `minimum 100% height`, will `scroll with page`.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure on how to give a minimum `height of 100%` and bring an `scroll with page`.

Comment: What do you mean by "scroll with page"?

Comment: Can you put your code in JSfiddle and share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicly, `display` properties using the table layout are just fine : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/44hN2/)**

```
html, body, .container {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    background:lightgray
}
.container {
    display:table;
    border-spacing:0.5em;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
.col-sm-4 {
    display:table-cell;
    background:white;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your 100% height container is inside the document body, make sure that your document body and html element both span 100% height as well.

Your css should have something like this:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

something like this:

```
html,body {height:100%;margin:0;background:#eee}
.container {height:100%}
.row {overflow:auto;height:100%;}
.col-sm-4 {height:100%;float:left;background:white;margin:0 1%;width:31.3333%}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S379x/